# Strange Null pointer exception on previously working code

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Very strange and frustrating error.

As soon as I load my app on the emulator and try to open it, I am receieving a null pointer exception error within the on create method.

As said in the title, this code has worked perfectly for weeks.

Here is the logcat:

```
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flybase2/com.example.flybase2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at com.example.flybase2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-14 20:03:45.813: E/AndroidRuntime(285):  ... 11 more
```

and here is the class:

```
package com.example.flybase2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button bContacts;
Button bAppointment;
Button bShopping;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.appmenus);

     bContacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCons);
     bAppointment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAppoint);
     bShopping = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShop);

    bContacts.setOnClickListener(this);
    bAppointment.setOnClickListener(this);
    bShopping.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View passedAppChoice) {
    switch(passedAppChoice.getId()){

    case (R.id.btnCons):
    Intent cons = new Intent("com.example.flybase2.contacts");
    startActivity(cons);
    break;

    case (R.id.btnAppoint):
        Intent Appoint = new Intent("com.example.flybase2.appointmantMenu");
        startActivity(Appoint);
        break;

    case (R.id.btnShop):
        Intent shop = new Intent("com.example.flybase2.ShoppingList");
        startActivity(shop);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Appmenus.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="84dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLink"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.91"
    android:src="@drawable/menulist" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="165dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.14"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Menu"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/consicon"
    android:src="@drawable/consicon"
    android:text="Contacts " />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnToDo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/todo"
    android:src="@drawable/todo"
    android:text="&apos;To Do&apos; List" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnShop"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="20dp"
       android:drawableLeft="@drawable/shoppingmenu"
       android:src="@drawable/shoppingmenu"
       android:text="Shopping List" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btnAppoint"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="20dp"
           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/appointmainicon"
           android:src="@drawable/appointmainicon"
           android:text="Appointment List" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hopefully someone can see where I have gone wrong!.

Comment: What line is it? For me, 33 can't cause an NPE: are you running the code you believe you are?

Comment: @DaveNewton how do you know what is line 33 in his code snippet.

Comment: Did you save the layout and remove/rename one of the items?  That's the only way I can see to get an NPE in that function

Comment: I just hate it when people do this. Post the code exactly as is in your editor else the line numbers get messed up!

Comment: @SajitKunnumkal I can count. That it's an `@Override` is why I asked what line it actually is.

Comment: @DaveNewton oh so you copy and pasted the code to a text file and counted. Wish stackoverflow had a way to show line numbers for code snippets

Comment: Please post `appmenus.xml`. (I counted the lines on this page, 33 isn't that big.)

Comment: @DaveNewton when you say 'what line is it' do you mean the error? Im not sure> I have no idea why this has stopped working. I was having an issue where I couldnt edit my XML layouts but I dont see how it could of affected this?

Comment: @user1352057 Of course I mean what line is the error. How can you "not be sure"? Can you not see your code?

Comment: @OP: There's no need to have more than 1 blank line between anything. This will reduce the confusion for the people trying to help you. Fix your code please, and then re-run so that the actual line number appears in the error (not the old 33).

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  
 at com.example.flybase2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)` Here the LogCat tells us the error is thrown on line 33, i.e. one of your Views isn't in your layout. (Also have you "cleaned" your project?)

Comment: @Sam I have added the xml layout. I have cleaned it numerous times.

Comment: Hmm, everything looks fine to me... What happened when "I was having an issue where I couldnt edit my XML layouts"?

Comment: @Sam this is what Im thinking is my error sadly. Up to now all of my layouts have been linearlayouts. I added a new XML file with a relative layout and from there on out I could make changes to my XML layouts i.e removes buttons...change text etc but these changes would not show when i ran the emulator i.e it would be as if I had made no changes at all. Funnily enough I could even comment code out and it would still run as if the code was there!?

Comment: Obviously, RelativeLayouts shouldn't have caused this problem... Have you done basic steps during a WTF moment like this: double checked that you are altering the correct `appmenus.xml` (not one in another `res` folder) and rebooted your computer, then cleaned the project again for good measure?

Comment: @Sam I only have the one appsmenu.xml in the whole project. All of the button id's are correct and I have rebooted eclipse and the laptop a number of times along with cleaning the project to no avail. I guess if worst comes to the worst i will have to start a new project as i have the code all backed up etc

Comment: :( I have never experienced this problem, so I'm out of ideas. Starting a new project then cutting & pasting the code into new files would be my next step...

Comment: @user1352057 : In Package Explorer you can right-click the project and select Delete - it won't delete the files from disk (unless you tell it to) it'll just delete the project from eclipse. When you've done that you can use New.. then Project and select Android Project from Existing Code. It might help - I had to do that once with one of my projects which started displaying strange behaviour.

Comment: I am not seeing the import of the R class, are you importing the good R class?

Answer (score 0):

## A Few Possible Things:

- Does `R.layout.appmenus` contain all the above buttons (check the IDs). Since R.id is an app-wide namespace, it could have been in other layouts too
- The way you're starting your intents seems odd. This is not how you start explicit intents.

An Explicit Intent should be of the form:

```
Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(InvokingActivity.this,InvokedActivity.class);
startActivity(explicitIntent);
```

Comment: What has the way he starts his Activities got to do with a NPE in his `onCreate(...)` method? Also, you don't "start Intents" - you use Intents to start Activities, Services etc.

Comment: @Squonk well, the string that he passed in will be converted to something and looked up for in his application manifest (or elsewhere) if not found and some action were to be taken on that it could raise an NPE

Comment: But that would still create a different stack trace. Also `appmenus.xml` is posted and contains all three ids...

Comment: @Squonk As to your starting activities and not intents... semantics, semantics ... well I understand what you're saying, but you're being unnecessarily tedious.

Comment: @Sam My bad, I guess I missed the XML, was the Q updated? It _might_ create a different stack trace, but that point is moot now.

Comment: @DheeB My last update was the appsmenu xml file. I have checked all the id's are matching and they do, no error is being shown when i run the code only a null pointer crash as soon as i try to open it. Obviously something went very badly wrong (and i should of seen it as a warning sign) when i could no longer see the changes i was making in the XML in the emulator. At this point in time i think i'll copy and paste the code into a new project.

Comment: @user1352057 if it was working earlier, why don't you compare it with local history? If in eclipse right click on project or file and goto compare with local history. That'll save you the time of copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

add this logs print in onCreate just after initializing buttons objects.

```
  Log.d("MainActivityTAG", "bContacts ="+bContacts+ ", bAppointment="+bAppointment+", bShopping="+bShopping);
```

it seems one of the button object from below code is `null`.

```
 bContacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCons);
 bAppointment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAppoint);
 bShopping = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShop);
```

above log print will let you know which button instance is `null`, and you ll get to know if you are getting button with wrong ID or setting wrong layout which doesn’t have one of these buttons defined.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually started a new project and simply copied the code over so it was very quick. It is working now. I have no idea what happened but believe it is down to some sort of corruption in my XML appmenu.xml file layout. For what ever reason I think the appointments button can no longer be 'seen' by eclipse even though it is clearly there and referenced by its ID. Many thanks to all who contributed.